# Positioning Sidebar depending on the container margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I'm developing a new full width layout, where I have the sidebar in the left side. The content of the page has a max-width and margin: 0 auto. The problem comes when I want to put this sidebar in the same area of the content and respect the margin auto. The only way I found to achieve this is trough JS.

Here is an example:

```js
(function(){

 var adjustSidebarPosition = function(){
    var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];  
    var containerBounding = container.getBoundingClientRect();  
    sidebar.style.left = containerBounding.left + 'px'; 
  }();
  
})();
```

```css
body{
  font-size: 16px;
}
.top-banner{
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #644FBF;
}

.sidebar{
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
}

.blue-bckg{
  background-color: #F2F9FD;
}

.container{
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.side-bar-padding{
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-banner">
  <div class="container side-bar-padding">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <h2>This is another hello World</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
  <h3>This is the sidebar</h3>
</aside>

<section class="blue-bckg">
  <div class="container side-bar-padding">
    <h2>This is the main content</h2>
    <p>
      The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container side-bar-padding">
    <h2>Another Content</h2>
    <p>
      The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators.

To achieve this, it would be necessary to have uniform grammar, pronunciation and more common words. If several languages coalesce, the grammar of the resulting language is more simple and regular than that of the individual languages.

The new common language will be more simple and regular than the existing European languages. It will be as simple as Occidental; in fact, it will be Occidental.

To an English person, it will seem like simplified English, as a skeptical Cambridge friend of mine told me what Occidental is. The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in their grammar, their pronunciation and their most common words. Everyone realizes why a new common language would be desirable: one could refuse to pay expensive translators. 
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Can we do this without JS?

Comment: So , what is your problem ??

Comment: can we use `.sidepane` inside `container side-bar-padding` .?

Comment: @AnzilkhaN. The problem is every time that I resize the page, I need a listener in JS. I want a clean way to do this

Comment: @JuanJardim , is this you want https://i.imgur.com/Yjnm7IJ.png ??

Comment: Question not clear